# Pull the dub out

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does it mean when someone says: “he pulled the dub out on his hockey game last night”?

What does “pulling the dub out” mean?

Comment: It's not an expression I'm familiar with. Where did you see or hear it? Can you please provide a source (ideally with a link)?

Answer (score 4):

***The dub*** in hockey, and other sports simply means *win*. *Dub* is the first sound in the letter *w*, the initial letter in *win*.

To *pull out* a dub, or, win, can mean to win a close game, or perhaps come from  behind in a game to win.

For example:

> TJ volleyball **pulling out the dub** on a clutch ace last set. Let's go tj keep grinding! Great job girls

from a [tweet](https://twitter.com/TJ_Squad/status/902739828021772288)

---

A different usage of *the Dub* in hockey is that it stands for the Western Hockey League (abbreviated WHL), with *dub* standing for the *W* in *western*.